# IAM Roles AnyWhere

Tags: permissions, amazon-iam

I've been using the IAM roles anywhere.
To Authenticate from your environment Your non AWS workloads authenticate via a certificate trusted by your trust anchor and obtain temporary credentials from a role. By using the following command

$ ./aws_signing_helper credential-process 
--certificate /path/to/certificate 
--private-key /path/to/private-key 
--trust-anchor-arn arn:aws:rolesanywhere:region:account:trust-anchor/TA_ID 
--profile-arn arn:aws:rolesanywhere:region:account:profile/PROFILE_ID 
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::account:role/role-name-with-path

But I am not sure, from where I want to take the certificate and private key